# Visual Basic CInt error

Tags: vba

I am trying to make a function that looks at an image, and return the X pixel value.

When i run the code, it throws an error on the Int1=CInt(Xdim) line, saying "Type Mismatch (10080)"

If i hard-code the value i am testing into Xdim, it works fine.

```
Function ImgXDim(filename As String) As Integer         ' Finds the X dimension in pixels of a loaded image
Dim objShell As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim ImgSize As String
Dim Int1 As Integer
Dim Xdim As String
Dim strarray() As String

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(MacroDir & "\PICS\")
Set objFile = objFolder.ParseName(filename)

ImgSize = objFile.ExtendedProperty("Dimensions")        ' Returns string of "700 x 923"

strarray = Split(ImgSize, " x ")                        ' Split into 2 strings of "700" and "923"
Xdim = CStr(strarray(0))                                ' Force Xdim to be a string of "700"
Int1 = CInt(Xdim)                                       ' Convert Xdim to an integer
ImgXDim = Int1                                          ' Return Integer

End Function
```

Comment: [Debug](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) your code. Then you'll see that Dimensions doesn't return exactly what you expected. [This](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/vba_debug2013.php) may help too.

Answer (score 1):

First check if value can be converted to an integer:

```
 If IsNumeric(Trim(Xdim)) then 
   Int1 = CInt(Xdim)
 else
   'for debug purposes
   MsgBox ("XDim non-numeric or empty")
 End If
```

Comment: You have tested `val(Xdim)`?

Comment: Yes. Val() function will return 0 for any non-numeric string and will not produce an error.

Comment: But doesn't return expected value (close to `On Error Resume Next`without thinking). With if condition you know something wrong and you can handle that, so I would prefer that of the two. Did you find his coding error? Then provide this instead as solution.

Comment: But didn't find the error in code. Look at the value of `objFile.ExtendedProperty("Dimensions") ` this causes the error (an unexpected character at the beginning). That's why `Xdim`is not a number.

Comment: I'm not seeing the leading character. When i run it through the built-in debugger, i get the following results... 

ImgSize -> "‪700 x 932‬"

strarray -> (0 To 1) As String

Xdim -> "‪700"

Comment: On `Ms-Access` I get`?700 x 187?`for a BMP. What app did you use? Another point for using`WIA`instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i couldnt find what character was causing the issue, so i used this loop of code to pull out only numbers, and it seems to work.

```
For X = 1 To Len(Xdim)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(Xdim, X, 1)) = True Then
       holder = holder & Mid(Xdim, X, 1)
    End If
Next X
```

Comment: Did you move the mouse over `ImgSize` when code breaks into error as my links suggested? I have a leading and ending `?`char that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here the [WIA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630368(v=vs.85).aspx) version:

```vb
Function ImgXDim(filename As String) As Long        
     Dim imgWIA as New WIA.ImageFile 'Early Binding needs a reference to Windows Image Aquisition Library in VBA-Ide->Tools->References
    'Dim imgWIA as Object 'Late Bound Version
    'Set imgWIA = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
    imgWIA.LoadFile MacroDir & "\PICS\" & filename
    ImgXDim = imgWIA.Width ' use .Height for height
End Function
```

As you see, just three lines of code and returns a long, not a string that needs parsing.

Useful functions for [resize](https://www.devhut.net/2017/01/18/vba-resize-image/), [rotate](https://www.devhut.net/2017/05/14/vba-wia-rotate-an-image/) and more.

Also useful if you want to display Tiffs in a picture control (page by page) and more.